# Giving an absolute position to a UICollectionViewCell

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

is it possible to control the layout of a `UICollectionViewCell` as to give it an absolute x or y position?

I want to use a `UICollectionView`, in each row of a table in order to create a simple 5 day calendar. At the moment I am just positioning a set of views with absolute x values in the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you will need to subclass `UIcollectionViewLayout`.

[This tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial) help me figure things out.

Comment: Thanks, I'll let you know how I get on when I create version 2.0